# Can I make instance methods not callable as static methods?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `@asynccontextmanager` method named `opened()` that is an instance method of a class `File`. Sometimes I call it using a class by mistake like so `File.opened()`. It then fails because the object is not initialized (e.g. name) with an error that does not really express the problem.

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'opened'

Is there a way to prevent this?

### Example

```
class File: 
   def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def opened(self):
        open(self.file_name)
        # do other things
```

This should be OK:

```
file = File('input.csv')
async with file.opened() as file_handle:
    #do stuff
```

But his should yield an error telling me that I can't use a instance method without creating an object first:

```
async with File.opened() as file_handle:
     # does not work, and should not be allowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `self` is an instance of `File` so that you can raise an exception with a friendlier error message:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def opened(self):
    if not isinstance(self, File):
        raise RuntimeError('opened() must be called as a method bound to a File instance.')
    open(self.file_name)
```